# Image pixel coordinates to world coordinate transformations

Tags: image-processing, matrix, linear-algebra, affinetransform

I'm asking this question from the perspective of non-mathematician.
So please dumb down answers as much as possible.

I'm using a microscope which has a camera and also a confocal scanning mode. The camera is slightly rotated counter clockwise relative to the physical stage orientation (0.53 degrees).

Furthermore, the camera has a slight lateral translation compared to the center of the stage. In other words, the center of the field of view (FOV) of the camera is offset compared to the center of the stage.
Specifically, my camera image has pixel dimensions of 2560, 2160. So the center of the camera FOV is 1280, 1080.
However, the center of the stage is actually at the image pixel coordinates 1355, 980.

My goal is to map objects detected in the image to their physical stage coordinate. We can assume the stage starts at physical coordinates 0,0 um.

The camera image has pixel size of 65nm.

Im not sure how to apply the transformations. (I know how to apply a simpler rotation matrix).

Could someone show me how to do this with a few example pixel coordinates in the camera image?

[Schematic representation of the shifts. WF means Widefield Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN3aH.png)

Comment: "affine transformation", even more constrained since you don't have shear, just translation, rotation, scaling -- you can play with transformations by constructing 3x3 matrices for each part of the transformation, and composing them (matrix multiplication). chop off the last row to get the affine part. libraries like OpenCV can take that and apply it to an image. -- some sample data please, so ppl have a chance to play and demonstrate.

Comment: I've been doing some tests with Excel conversion of coordinates.

Based on my example, do you think I should do rotation matrix first then the shift the origin, or origin first then rotation?
Okay I'll load data asap.

Comment: rotate, then translate. you'll recognize each component in the product of both matrices.